# For matrix $A$, if $A^4 = 0$ does this also mean that $A^2 = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

> For an arbitrary matrix $A$,  if $A^4 = 0$ does this also mean that $A^2 = 0$?

My thinking is that it does since I can reduce $A^4$ into $(A^2)^2$ but I'm not sure if this helps or not.

Comment: In general, $ab=0$ implies either $a=0$ or $b=0$ does't hold for matrices!

Comment: It's true if the size of $A$ is at most $2$ ( and the entries are in a field).

Comment: For clarification: the yellow part of the original question is true for 2-by-2 matrices over a field as the last comment says, but the statement '$ab=0$ implies either $a=0$ or $b=0$' from the comment just above it is not.

Comment: There are many patterns how rank of matrix can be decreasing.  Study Jordan forms with zeros on diagonal.

Answer (score 17):

$$\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}$$

Comment: Do you not also need to show that this is the square of some matrix $A$?

Comment: @Mjiig No, since it's not a square of a matrix.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted the answer. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Another counterexample, when the matrix elements are taken from $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, which is a commutative ring with a zero divisor:
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 1&1},\ A^2=\pmatrix{0&-2\\ 2&0},\ A^4=-4I=0.
$$
But surely, one can construct even an $1\times1$ counterexample, such as $A=2$ over $\mathbb Z/2^4\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Assumedly if you're using rings with zero divisors, this is a less interesting question, since you can already have $a^4 = 0$ but $a^2 \neq 0$ for scalars!

Comment: @Joppy Thanks. I was just about to say this when you posted your comment. I think a counterexample with $A$ being *not* a diagonal matrix would still be interesting.